# for loop with double condition

Tags: python, code-readability

I'm looking for a loop construct like `for i in list where i < n`. I would like to replace this mess:

```
for i in list:
    if i < n:
        #logic here
```

Is there something more compact and more elegant?

Comment: I'd say that this is the easiest and fastest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write it with a guard condition to avoid the layer of indentation.

```
for i in list:
    if i >= n: continue
```

A one-liner is this:

```
for i in (k for k in list if k < n):
    ...
```

But I think the obvious code with the if inside the loop is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.ifilter` as follows:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> inlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> for i in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x < 5,inlist):
...     print i
1
2
3
4
```

If you want the reverse condition, e.g. greater than:

```
>>> inlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> for i in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x > 5, inlist):
...     print i
... 
6
7
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

You could of course do this:

```
for i in (a for a in lst if a < n):
    # logic
```

But obviously that's a lot messier than your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in [x for x in list if x<n]:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In python for this kind of things you have to use `while`, the for loop is iterating the `list` you just gave it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [itertools.takewhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) would do what you want.

From the mothership:

`itertools.takewhile(predicate, iterable)`

Make an iterator that returns elements from the iterable as long as the predicate is true. Equivalent to:

```
def takewhile(predicate, iterable):
    # takewhile(lambda x: x<5, [1,4,6,4,1]) --> 1 4
    for x in iterable:
        if predicate(x):
            yield x
        else:
            break
```

**EDIT** *!ignore me!* as Karl says `ifilter(...)` is the correct solution.

`takewhile` is only useful as they say on the mothership:

> *Make an iterator that returns elements from the iterable as long as the predicate is true.*

I'd change that to be

> *Make an iterator that returns elements from the iterable **only** as long as the predicate is true.*

As Buffy would say:

> My bad.

Comment: `ifilter` is a better match for what OP describes than `takewhile`.